# Minor Syntax issue regarding Swift 3.0 and a for loop

Tags: xcode, swift, for-loop, swift3, xcode8

I recently just converted my code to the Swift 3.0 syntax that came with the Xcode 8 beta. I ran into several lines of code that I needed to change in order for the code to work with the latest syntax. I was able to correct all lines of code **except** for an error that I get regarding a for loop that I use to allow my background image to loop continuously.

The exact error message that I get is: **Ambiguous reference to member '..<'**

```
for i:CGFloat in 0 ..< 3 {

        let background = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: backgroundTexture.size().width/2 + (backgroundTexture.size().width * i), y: self.frame.midY)
        background.size.height = self.frame.height
        background.run(movingAndReplacingBackground)
        self.addChild(background)

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a floating point type as loop index

```
for i in 0 ..< 3 {
    let background = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
    background.position = CGPoint(x: backgroundTexture.size().width/2 + (backgroundTexture.size().width * CGFloat(i)), y: self.frame.midY)
    background.size.height = self.frame.height
    background.run(movingAndReplacingBackground)
    self.addChild(background)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
for i in 0..<3{

    let index = CGFloat(i)
    //Your Code
    let background = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
    background.position = CGPoint(x: backgroundTexture.size().width/2 + (backgroundTexture.size().width * index), y: self.frame.midY)
    background.size.height = self.frame.height
    background.run(movingAndReplacingBackground)
    self.addChild(background)
}
```

The problem is you are performing for-loop on `Int` and you are also specifying it as a `CGFloat`. So, there a confusing between both the types.